# How can I define ImageView with height width and source defined on xml file?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, fragment

Inflating view on fragment causing remove the attributes, how can I define ImageView with height width and source defined on xml file?

I am using this code bellow. for *image_fragment.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ImageFragment"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="test Image"
        tools:src="@drawable/cartoon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Using kotlin class for the fragment

ImageFragment.kt

```
class ImageFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment, container, false)


        return root
    }

}
```

It showing **nothin**. When I tried debugging tools, I found that, the height and width of the imageview is not defined so is resource of the image.

only if I use

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment, container, false)
        root.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.cartoon)


        return root
    }
```

it is **showing** the image. But attributes are still missing.

**So what should do to define attributes and image source in xml file?**

Answer (score 0):

you are using `tools` in `xml`, it only shows a preview.

you must use `app:srcCompat`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="test Image"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cartoon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

as **document** said

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
> namespace that enables design-time features (such as which layout to
> show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
> mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the
> build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
> size or runtime behavior.

so `tools:src="@drawable/cartoon"` just shows in **designing UI preview** and it will be **removed** at **build time**.
use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/cartoon"` instead of `tools:src="@drawable/cartoon"`

also for using `app:srcCompat` in your XML file, make sure to do the following:
setup your **build.gradle** file

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables {
      useSupportLibrary = true
    }
  }
}
```